# Не получается реализовать методы у объекта с python python-c-api

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

Написан биндинг с С в питон, но у объектов, которые мы передаем в python, нет созданных методов, до тех пор, пока мы не вызовем dir(object)

Код на C

```cpp
static PyObject *some_method(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    std::cout << "its work" << std::endl;
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyMethodDef SomeMethods[] = {
  {"some_method", some_method, METH_VARARGS},
  {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL},
};

typedef struct
{
    PyObject_HEAD
    PyObject *ptr;
} structOfType;

static void ptr_obj_dealloc(structOfType *t)
{
    Py_DECREF((structOfType *)(t)->ptr);
    PyObject_DEL(t);
}

static PyObject * Custom_new(PyTypeObject * type, PyObject * args, PyObject * kwargs) {
    return type->tp_alloc(type, 0);
}

static int Custom_init(structOfType * self, PyObject * args, PyObject * kwargs) {
    return 0;
}

PyTypeObject someType = {
        PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    .tp_name = "myinstance",
        .tp_basicsize = sizeof(structOfType),
    .tp_itemsize  = 0,
        .tp_dealloc = (destructor)ptr_obj_dealloc,
        .tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE,
        .tp_doc = "some docs..",
        .tp_methods = SomeMethods,
    .tp_init = (initproc) Custom_init,
    .tp_new = Custom_new,
};
```

Дальше пытаемся вызвать в python

```py
def test():
  print(hasattr(myinstance, "some_method")) # false
  myinstance.some_method() # AttributeError: 'myinstance' object has no attribute 'some_method'


#########


def test():
  print(dir(myinstance))
  print(hasattr(myinstance, "some_method")) # true
  myinstance.some_method() # its work
```

C **dir()** все работает, без него вылетает исключение **AttributeError**.

Тыкните на ошибку, пожалуйста, если кто знает.

Comment: а где функция инициализации модуля (`PyMODINIT_FUNC
initmy_mod_name()`, или что-то подобное)? и на всякий пожарный, как ты это всё собираешь и вызываешь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил. Перед `PyObject_NEW` надо использовать `PyType_Ready`
К примеру:

```
PyType_Ready(&SomeType)

Example *example = PyObject_NEW(Example, &SomeType)
```